# How to resolve the proper IP address of a server?

Tags: ip, domain-name

The server is "dlftp_int.danlawinc.com" tracert is only giving 192.168.x.x addresses. I want the proper IP address; which online tools cannot seem to provide because of the underscore in the name.

Comment: Try pinging it.

Comment: The "int" in dlftp_int, does that stand for internal? Is the server exposed to internet? Tried to quickly ping and trace it and the DNS-lookup failed, and it's not because of the underscore.

Comment: This was an internal server; If you guys cannot get to it; then I suppose its not exposed after all. Thanks very much.

Comment: The server might be exposed, but there's no public DNS record for the dlftp_inc server on that domain, so it's probably some internal DNS-server within the LAN that takes care of that routing, internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The server is `dlftp_int.danlawinc.com`

That is an invalid domain name - <kbd>_</kbd>  is not an allowed character.

That is why the online tools remove this character (and other not allowed characters) when you try and use them.

Using this character **may** work on private networks but will fail if the server needs to be exposed to the public internet.

According to [RFC 1035 - Domain Implementation and Specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035) each part of a domain (or label) must start with a alpha character, end with an alpha or numeric character, and include only alpha, numeric or <kbd>-</kbd>  (hyphen) characters.

See section 2.3.1 of [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035):

> ```
> <domain> ::= <subdomain> | " "
>
> <subdomain> ::= <label> | <subdomain> "." <label>
>
> <label> ::= <letter> [ [ <ldh-str> ] <let-dig> ]
>
> <ldh-str> ::= <let-dig-hyp> | <let-dig-hyp> <ldh-str>
>
> <let-dig-hyp> ::= <let-dig> | "-"
>
> <let-dig> ::= <letter> | <digit>
>
> <letter> ::= any one of the 52 alphabetic characters A through Z in
> upper case and a through z in lower case
>
> <digit> ::= any one of the ten digits 0 through 9
> ```
>
> Note that while upper and lower case letters are allowed in domain
> names, no significance is attached to the case.  That is, two names
> with the same spelling but different case are to be treated as if
> identical.
>
> The labels must follow the rules for ARPANET host names.  They must
> start with a letter, end with a letter or digit, and have as interior
> characters only letters, digits, and hyphen.  There are also some
> restrictions on the length.  Labels must be 63 characters or less.

The historical reason is that domain names are not case sensitive - and on many keyboards <kbd>_</kbd>  is the same as <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>